# Named query returns java.sql.Timestamp instead of java.util.Date

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate 5.3.13

I am querying for a date with a named query:

```
    public Date getDate() {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("MyEntity.myNamedQuery", Date.class)
                            //setting some parameters here
                            .getSingleResult();
    }
```

Column definition:

```
    @Column(name="date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;
```

This query works fine but hibernate returns java.sql.Timestamp when I want java.util.Date.

Is it possible to make hibernate return Date instead of Timestamp?

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` is a subtype of `java.util.Date`. What specifically is wrong with this?

Comment: Also, why not use new `java.time` types, like a `LocalDateTime` or a `ZonedDateTime`, which both naturally have nanosecond precision and have better APIs, as well as a ready type for a date without time - the `LocalDate`

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Legacy project, moving everything to new time API is a lot of work. Problem is that for example timestamp.before(date) works differently than date.before(date)

Comment: Ultimately, both `before` calls compare `getTime()`, the only difference is comparing nanoseconds. They work the same if timestamp doesn't have nanoseconds. That's one way to work around it. There's another - do what developers always did when working with `j.u.Date` and never call a method on it directly, surround it with think wall of utility methods. Or just bite it and refactor to use new types at least in this limited capacity. There are factories that allow some interfacing with old types, to ease you into it.

Comment: In the end I convert both variables to Instant and compare Instants.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [*Hibernate – Mapping Date and Time*](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-date-time):

> As we've seen, the java.util.Date type (milliseconds precision) is not precise enough to handle the Timestamp value (nanoseconds precision).
>
> So when we retrieve the entity from the database, we'll unsurprisingly find a java.sql.Timestamp instance in this field, even if we initially persisted a java.util.Date:
>
> [...]
>
> This should be fine for our code since Timestamp extends Date.

You can just cast the returned value to `Date`.

Check out the reference in general, it has more details for you.

Comment: I can do new Date(timestamp.getTime()) but I hoped there is a possibility that hibernate would handle it.